# PHP generate foreach and generate it as array

Tags: php, arrays, random, foreach

please help I need create some array random from this case:

```
foreach (range(1,3) as $number) { 
$lala1= "\"img$number\",";
$lala2 = array("$lala1");
echo $lala2[array_rand($lala2)];
}
```

Is give me this result:

```
"img1","img2","img3",
```

but I need the result to show random like this:

```
img1 (with random img1,img2, or img3)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a one element array (`$lala2`) and "randomizing" it on each iteration, which is why you get all 3 elements printed out.

What you need to do is add a new element on each iteration, and only then use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to pick a random element out of the resulting array:

```
<?php
$imgs = []; // define the array where you'll store the elements
foreach (range(1,3) as $number) { 
    $lala1 = "\"img$number\",";
    $imgs[] = $lala1; // add the new element to the array
}
echo $imgs[array_rand($imgs)]; // pick a random value
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UrGu6)

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was typing up. Beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the array each time through the loop, not replace it, and then use `array_rand()` after the loop.

```
$lala2 = array();
foreach (range(1, 3) as $number) {
    $lala1 = "\"$img$number\",";
    $lala2[] = $lala1;
}
echo $lala2[array_rand($lala2)];
```